# How can I set block size of output files produced by a Hadoop Streaming job?

Tags: streaming, hadoop

Seems like this should be simple; I have a set of files on our cluster with the cluster-default block size of 128MB.  I have a streaming job that process them, and I would like the output files created by the streaming job to use a different block size, specifically 16MB.  I thought the following would work:

> $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/contrib/streaming/hadoop-0.20.1+152-streaming.jar -D dfs.block.size=16777216 -D mapred.job.name='Log Processor' -D mapred.reduce.tasks=5 -D mapred.output.compress=true -D mapred.output.compression.type=BLOCK -input /production/beacon/vbox*/20110609/00/access_log -output /user/me/logprocess/20110609/00/access_log -mapper /bin/cat -outputformat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileOutputFormat

No love, the files produced at /user/me/logprocess/20110609/00/access_log all use the default block size for the cluster of 128MB.  I've tried replacing dfs.block.size with fs.local.block.size in the command as well, with the same results.  Any ideas how to control this in a streaming job?

Answer (score -1):

It won't be an "exact" block size, but what you could do is set the # of reducers. How this works is that each reducer outputs one file, so if you know your OUTPUT file is 128MB (input is irrelevant) and you wanted each of your output files to not exceed 16K each, you could assign 8 reducers (128/16). NOTE: files will likely be *roughly* 16K each, and there is no guarantee that all files will be < 16K.